# Make a java based Rest call with Oauth Consumer key,secret, access token and token secret

Tags: java, rest, oauth

So I am trying to make an API call with rest-client on browser with oauth Consumer key,secret, access token and token secret and it woks fine as shown below.

Please advise how can this be done in Java ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lE06d.jpg

All the oauth show the whole process but once the key and tokens are saved after the first time,
how to make the API call is the question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like [Google oAuth Java Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/). Samples are [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/Samples).

Comment: Thanks for the response. My bad I should have mentioned I need this for oauth 1.0. But the sample code is using oauth 2 :(

Comment: This library supports oath 1.0 also. https://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/wiki/OAuth1