# How can I consume a rest webservice with oauth 1.0a using spring?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, oauth

I have a Spring MVC WebApp and a wordpress site with wp api configured alongside oauth 1.0a authentication.

I have the following values to authenticate:
oauth_consumer_key
oauth_consumer_secret
oauth_token
oauth_token_secret

I am passing these values on the "Authoriaztion" tab using POSTMAN app for chrome and i can successfully consume.

I tried to consume with spring but, with Spring i couldn't find where to put the above parameters.

I tried this and it worked:
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-oauth-10a-authentication--cms-24797

I found this:
[Make a java based Rest call with Oauth Consumer key,secret, access token and token secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26308464/make-a-java-based-rest-call-with-oauth-consumer-key-secret-access-token-and-tok)

But cant't seem to understand how to implement on oauth 1.0a with  oauth_consumer_key oauth_consumer_secret oauth_token oauth_token_secret.

Any link that might help?

Comment: Hello Kunal . Did you find the answer ?

Comment: Hi @WannaBeGeek I did not, sorry. Although what i needed was to communicate between a wordpress (php) based website with an java web (spring) site. So i used a plugin in wordpress called JSON API and made my very own authentication methods

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I need to do the same . Connect Spring and WordPress . I will look into JSON API plugin .

Comment: @WannaBeGeek Your welcome. Here you have a link: https://pt.wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/ and let me know if you need help